# Deleting multiple vertices at once from representations using ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, representation, vertices

I have a polygon feature class that I've converted to representations so that I can delete some vertices.

I'm doing this to simplify some of the shapes manually, but I'd like to speed this up by selecting a group of vertices with the Representations lasso tool and then deleting them at once rather then using the time-consuming point-and-click Delete Vertex tool.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Apparently, the [ArcGIS Idea to Delete Multiple Verticies [sic]](http://ideas.arcgis.com/ideaView?id=0873000000087r7AAA#comments) was implemented in ArcGIS Desktop 10, so as long as you are using that version (or later) you should be able to use it.

Comment: and beautifully it works too! I love it.

Comment: I concur. this functionality was badly needed. Saves a lot of time.

Comment: That seems to only work for editing actual features, not representations though?

Comment: @EightyTwenty ... but you said that you "converted to representations so that I can delete some vertices" so that now seems to be an unnecessary step.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using a earlier version pre ArcGIS 10 you could use the following tools:

[Vertex Tool](http://arcscripts.esri.com/details.asp?dbid=14451)

[Delete Multiple Vertex by drawing a polygon](http://arcscripts.esri.com/details.asp?dbid=12565)

Answer (score 1):

Click the Delete Vertex tool on the Edit Vertices toolbar and drag a box around the vertices to delete. You can also hold down **D** and drag a box, or press **BACKSPACE**, to delete selected vertices.

[image]

http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//001t00000097000000.htm

Comment: That seems to only work for editing actual features, not representations though?